# How to choose a Mock framework for web application running on Java EE and what is general important Mock framework?

Tags: spring, frameworks, junit, mocking

I need your help in choosing mock framework.
I'm a junior developer of web application in Java EE with Maven, Spring and Hibernate. We have many jUnit tests for DAO and service layer. Now I got a new task: use mock objects for testing.

First question is: what mock framework I have to choose?
Our tests are based on Spring injections (from second, test-only, application context) and many of tests using connection to testing database. The idea of my superior is include mock framework to all tests. I don't know if it is necessary. I think that would be enough to use only as a simulating test database, to avoid the danger that the database does not run. What do you think about it?

And second question follows first question: what is general important of Mock framework with using jUnit and Spring in my tests? What I understood from the examples on Mock framework, using Spring components as defined in the application context and inject them into the test classes is the same as defined Mock objects in the application context (it is obviously about the same object definitions, just call it the Mock object) and injecting them into the test classes. The only addition is a new methods of Mock framework?

Please try help me choose the right framework and understand using Mock objects in my case.

Thanks!

PS: and sorry for my bad english ;-)

Comment: On SO, asking for suggestions is considered Not Constructive (sometimes off-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally in Spring there is a test framework included (Read more about: `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`)

You can test DB stuff in a transaction which is automatically rolled back after test.

If it comes to general mock framework I propose ***Mockito***.

Comment: Of course that we used '@Transactional' annotation for class and '@Rollback' annotation for methods which changing anything in database. It is therefore I don't completely understand what Mock framework bring new to our app.